# Mocking does not work as expected (Django)

Tags: django, mocking, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-django

I have this code:

// **app1.service.py**

```
database = {
    1: "Alice",
    2: "Bob",
    3: "Charlie"
}


def get_user_from_db(user_id):
    return database.get(user_id)
```

// **app1.tests.test_service.py**

```
import pytest
from unittest import mock

from app1.service import get_user_from_db


@mock.patch("app1.service.get_user_from_db")
def test_get_user_from_db(mock_get_user_from_db):
    mock_get_user_from_db.return_value = "Mocked Alice"
    username = get_user_from_db(1)  # If I change it to mock_get_user_from_db(1) everything works fine
    assert username == "Mocked Alice"
```

When i run 'pytest' in the command line, I get this:

```
E       AssertionError: assert 'Alice' == 'Mocked Alice'
E         - Mocked Alice
E         + Alice
```

In the tutorial I am watching, **get_user_from_db(1)** returns **"Mocked Alice",** but in my local machine it returns just **"Alice"**. It works fine when I use

```
username = mock_get_user_from_db(1)
```

instead of the

```
username = get_user_from_db(1)
```

**Question: It this the expected behaviour that username = get_user_from*db(1) returns "Alice" in my case?** (in the youtube video it returns "Mocked Alice") **or am I just doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import it *after* mocking, otherwise it still refers to the *old* non-mocked item:

```
from unittest import mock

import pytest


@mock.patch("app1.service.get_user_from_db")
def test_get_user_from_db(mock_get_user_from_db):
    mock_get_user_from_db.return_value = 'Mocked Alice'

    from app1.service import get_user_from_db

    username = get_user_from_db(
        1
    )  # If I change it to mock_get_user_from_db(1) everything works fine
    assert username == "Mocked Alice"
```

The mocking tool can not change the behavior of the original object, so basically, it replaces it by a function that acts differently.